# Delete all occurrences from JSON Array

Tags: json, removechild

I have a 32MB-JSON-file which I represents a database. It has the following structure:

```
{ 
  "Players": [
         {
            "item1":"A"
            "item2":"B"
            "item3":"C"
         },
         {
            "item1":"D"
            "item2":"E"
            "item3":"F"
         }
         {
           ...
         }
   ]
}
```

In order to reduce its weight, i'd like to delete all "item1" and all its associated values. Which is the best way to do it? I mean manually with any text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Sublime Text for this:

1. Select Find > Replace
2. Switch to Regular Expressions (Alt + R)
3. In Find What enter this regular expression:

   .*"item1".*\n
4. Leave the Replace with empty
5. Click Replace All

After that your sample looks like this:

```
{ 
  "Players": [
         {
            "item2":"B"
            "item3":"C"
         },
         {
            "item2":"E"
            "item3":"F"
         }
         {
           ...
         }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Finally I did it using C# but your answer is better!